# How to Integrate Mupdf in android studio step by step?

Tags: mupdf

i am a new developer curreently working on a project that need to use mupdf but it's really complicated to integrate.
Is there any tutorial and anyone can tell me to that step by step in a specific detail?
please thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that shows one way to integrate mupdf to android:

[MuPDF Android Integration](http://ssahinkoc.blogspot.sg/2014/10/integration-of-mupdf-project-as-library.html)

It's written by Şahin Koç.

Hope this helps.